# How to stop Android ViewFlipper from looping?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view

I have a ViewFlipper set to auto-flip every 5 seconds.  Leaving out some of the details, it looks like this and works fine:

```
ViewFlipper flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.myflipperid);

flipper.setFlipInterval(5000);                              
flipper.setInAnimation(inFromRightAnimation());
flipper.setOutAnimation(outToLeftAnimation());

flipper.startFlipping();
```

However, I have a case where I want the auto-flipping to stop at the last view, rather than looping around to start over again.  It doesn't seem that ViewFlipper or any of the classes it inherits from have a looping control method.

How can I get ViewFlipper to stop looping through its child views when it hits the last one?

Note: the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354180/how-to-prevent-viewflipper-from-looping) doesn't apply to my case, as I need to catch the ViewFlipper at the end of its list, i.e., without depending on user input.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't tried this my self but I hope this will help.

First, Try to listen to your viewflipper's flip events. 
Since you are using an animation. You may use the solution posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3813179/1594522

Then, onAnimationEnd(), you can check if the viewflipper is on its last child view.
If it is already on its last child view, then call flipper.stopFlipping().

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I did yesterday. You beat me in posting an answer, so I'll give you the checkmark! My actual solution is posted below.

Answer (score 9):

Here's the solution I used.  As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3813179/1594522), the trick is to listen for the end of animation event, and then check to see if the flipper is on the last view.

```
flipper.getInAnimation().setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

        int displayedChild = flipper.getDisplayedChild();
        int childCount = flipper.getChildCount();

        if (displayedChild == childCount - 1) {
            flipper.stopFlipping();
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: What is "flipperWall" in your example?

Comment: Sorry, I left out the declaration.  In this example, flipperWall is just a view flipper, like this: ViewFlipper flipperWall;.  You'll also need to initialize it from an XML file, using findViewById(), or by doing it programmatically.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just get the size of the list, and then in the if condition, say

```
flipper.stopFlipping()
```

Hope it works this way.